# Asyncio run_util_complete method cousing error

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, okta-api

I'm consuming the Okta API

```
import csv
import asyncio
from okta.client import Client as OktaClient
from okta import models

config = {
    'orgUrl': '',
    'token': ''
}

okta_client = OktaClient(config)

async def main(): 
    with open(r'C:\Users\user\Downloads\Export Users 2023-07-26 20-20-57.csv') as csv_file:
        csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in csv_reader:

            user, resp, err = await okta_client.get_user(line['Primary email'])
            print(user.profile.email)
            new_profile = user.profile
            new_profile.email = line['New primary email']
            updated_user_obj = models.User({'profile': new_profile})
            updated_user, _, err = await okta_client.update_user(user.id, updated_user_obj)
            
        print('Users upddated')
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

And I'm getting None type for the user object but seems to be because the run_until_complete method is failing as that error comes first on the trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hami_\Documents\Stagwell\Okta\Okta Automations\bulk_user_update_primaryemail.py", line 28, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Users\hami_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\hami_\Documents\Stagwell\Okta\Okta Automations\bulk_user_update_primaryemail.py", line 20, in main
    print(user.profile.email)
```

Comment: You need to show us the complete traceback. You've failed to include the actual error message. You would normally replace your two lines of code with `asyncio.run(main())`.

Comment: I just updated my question

Comment: That is how the traceback works. It _ends_ with the line causing the error. This has nothing to do with `run_until_complete` (even though you should use `asyncio.run`). `user` is `None` (for whatever reason).